# Lambda custom names in pycharm aws toolkit

Tags: aws-lambda, pycharm, aws-toolkit

When I am creating lambda via pycharm AWS Toolkit, it appends a name to the lambda function I create.  Therefore name of a function is something like "hello-world-12MJU0DB7Y99B".  While it is OK for custom functions, it is not something that I can easily use to automate multi-account AWS environment.  I need the name of the function to be "hello-world".

Is there anyway to specify exact function name?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pycharm and the AWS Toolkit, but something like this happens automatically when you don't define the function name (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-functionname) when creating it. AWS then creates the function with a "human comprehensible but unique" name. Can you declare the function name somewhere in the framework?

Comment: thank you! I was working with serverless previously and didn't need to set the name, but with pycharm I have to.  Wonderful.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution was indeed as Milan cermak suggested, unlike in serverless aws toolkit requires name variable to be set.  Once that is done the name is as expected!